# c# sqlite.codefirst - what does this error mean

Tags: sqlite

Trying to make sqlite work with entity framework 6. The intended app is going to be a windows forms app. Here's what I did so far:

1. nu-get manager console: install-package sqlite.codefirst
   --> succeeded
2. created a class 'students' with three properties
3. went to app.config, which currently is looking like this:

   ```
   <configuration>
   <configSections>
   <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
   <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
   </configSections>
   <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"    />
   </startup>
   <entityFramework>
   <!--defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
   <parameters>
   <parameter value="v11.0" />
   </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory-->
   <providers>
   <!--provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" /-->
   <!--provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" /-->
   <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite"/>
   </providers>
   </entityFramework>  
   <connectionStrings>
   <add name="SurveyDbContext" connectionString=" data source = .\SQLite; initial catalog=TimerDB; integrated security = SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
4. Created a class that inherits from DbContext:

   ```
   public class SurveyDbContext : DbContext
   {
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SurveyDbContext>(modelBuilder);
           Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
       }

       public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. went to nu-get manager console again:
   enable-migrations

I get a folder called "Migrations", but it actually contains no migration. Therefore the following error message: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

What exactly am I supposed to do?
Thank you very much!